# How can I convert Multidimensional Database to Tabular Model In SSAS

Tags: multidimensional-array, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, ssas, tabular

I use `SSAS` in `SQL Server 2008 R2` and I Migrate to `SQL Server 2012 SP1`

I has `Multidimensional Database Model` In `SQL Server 2008 R2` but now I have `Tabular Model`.

I have 8 `Multidimensional Database` in `SSAS 2008 R2`.

How Can I Convert these 8 databases to `SSAS 2012 SP1` with different Model?

Comment: Is there a reason to convert to the tabular model? SSAS 2012 supports teh multidimensional model as well.

Comment: @FrankPl : I want use SharePoint Power Pivot and I think that in situation I have to use SSAS in tabular mode. Now I have 8 Multidimensional Database and more that 30 Cube in Dimensional Mode. Should I convert my Multidimensional Database to Tabular mode?

Comment: As documented here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492165.aspx, you can use cubes as sources for each table in a tabular model. But apart from that, there is not much support for conversion, as far as I am aware. And even then, it would probably make more sense to directly access the relational tables on which the cubes are based than to go through the cube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @FrankPl mentioned, there is no way to convert from SSAS multidimensional to SSAS tabular. If that is truly a requirement, then the best approach is to build the Tabular from scratch based on the same source used by the existing SSAS multidimensional.

> @FrankPl : I want use SharePoint Power Pivot and I think that in
>   situation I have to use SSAS in tabular mode. Now I have 8
>   Multidimensional Database and more that 30 Cube in Dimensional Mode.
>   Should I convert my Multidimensional Database to Tabular mode? –  loup

PowerPivot with SharePoint uses a "special" type of SSAS tabular instance (see [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471594.aspx)). The only way to deploy models to the PowerPivot SSAS instance is to upload PowerPivot workbooks to SharePoint. SharePoint then extracts the PowerPivot model from the Excel workbook and publishes it to the PowerPivot SSAS instance. You should not deploy a SSAS tabular model created in SSDT/VisualStudio to this PowerPivot SSAS instance (truth be told, I'm not actually sure if the software prevents this)...because this instance is optimized for many small tabular models (as opposed to a few larger tabular models).

Furthermore, if you're only requirement is to use SharePoint + PowerView and your SSAS Multidimensional instance/server is at least version 2012 **SP1 Cumulative Update 4**, then you don't need to worry about converting to SSAS tabular. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198310.aspx) for details.